# python crashes on build script: event log indicates CRYPT32.dll error

Tags: python, windows, dll

platform: windows 2008 server R2
this is the error the event log is producing:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x52c9534c
Faulting module name: CRYPT32.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18741, time stamp: 0x54d03c46
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0005d412
Faulting process id: 0xcf8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1bff8ffe076da
Faulting application path: C:\python27\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
```

anyone ever saw something like this?

I'm using python 2.7.5. could this be the problem?
it's not a standard version of python. anyone got the same error or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: seems like I've solved it.
running the scripts through python does not produce error codes, so I ran it via installshield UI, and got some more information.
After an extensive research, I found this:
﻿﻿https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/ERRDOC/Q107380

TL;DR - three windows updates mess up the install shield installations.
these - KB3004394, KB2949927, and KB3033929
after removing all three of them, the build now works.

This does not happen on installshield after 2012 version. only versions prior to that.